# Unable to send commands to CMD through Streams in java

Tags: java, process, stream

I'm trying to open an application(RCMIClient.exe) through CMD. I was able to open the CMD but cannot read or write commands to CMD. Below is the code,  there are no errors, it just opens CMD and does nothing, but when I close the CMD manually I get below error.

```
null
Exception in thread "main" 
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
at test.test.main(test.java:36)
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    File f = new File("C:\\WDGSIMTools\\Anite\\RCMI\\Samples\\Release");
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c","start").directory(f);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
    BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    String errline;
    errline = error.readLine();
    System.out.println(errline);

    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
        output.append(line);

    }
    //To test whether its reading CMD contents
    System.out.println(output);

    //send commands to CMD 
    writer.write("RCMIClient.exe"+"\n");
    writer.flush();
    writer.write("1"+"\n");
    writer.close();
    reader.close();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.exe /c start` will launch a child process then close.

You are attempting to direct input to the original cmd (which closed).

Instead you should invoke `cmd.exe /C RCMIClient.exe`

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I made the changes and it did open the application but in the background. Do you have any idea how to get it to forehand?

Comment: @Rajesh try using Process.waitFor after sending the "1\n"

Comment: @Rajesh Look at it this way... you are already running a CLI application when you run this java program. So if you want to display output of the subprocess, you should do it by redirecting to System.out. If that isn't good enough and it has to be in a separate window, I guess you could do `cmd.exe /C start java HelperProgram`

Comment: Thanks Patrick, Actually "cmd.exe","/c","start","RCMIClent.exe" worked. It pops up CMD and my application is waiting for input in CMD.